# SQL query to return one unix time to represent a day

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need to inform the user the days when an alert took place.

I have an alerts_table in my database which stores the unixtime and alerts that took place during that time.

```
select DISTINCT unixtime from alerttable; // returns all alerts
```

The problem is that i have thousands of alerts happening per day and i just want my query to return one UNIX time representing each day
, so that i can tell the user if he had an alert on particular days.

Then i can convert the unix times to Days and show the user
(example: You had an alert on 11/11/2023 , 12/11/2023 etc )

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it works:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(unixTime) AS unixtime, 
  TRUNC(TO_DATE( '1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) 
        + NUMTODSINTERVAL(unixTime, 'SECOND' )) AS "day"
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY 
  TRUNC(TO_DATE( '1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) 
        + NUMTODSINTERVAL(unixTime, 'SECOND' ))
ORDER BY 1;
```

So we use the function `NUMTODSINTERVAL` (see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions117.htm#SQLRF00682)) in order to get the amount of seconds from the unixtime.

Since the unix time by its definition "starts" on `1970-01-01`, we can add the seconds to this date and will get the date from the unixtime value.

Now we use `TRUNC` to get rid of the exact time and focus on the date only. So we can `GROUP BY` the date only and just select one unixtime per day (or the day itself if we prefer that).

We have to decide which unix time we select. I have chosen the first per day using `MIN`.

The `ORDER BY` clause sorts the result starting with the earliest day.

We can try out this solution on this [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sfm_eILJ)

Answer (score 0):

Convert unixtime to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (in the UTC time zone, since unix time is measured from 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) and then `TRUNC`ate to the start of the day:

If your `unixtime` is in seconds then:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * unixtime)
         AS day
FROM   alerttable
GROUP BY
       TRUNC(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * unixtime)
```

If `unixtime` is in milliseconds then:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND * unixtime)
         AS day
FROM   alerttable
GROUP BY
       TRUNC(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND * unixtime)
```